# Adding new button into virtual keyboard of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to add new button into virtual keyboard of iPhone (keyboard that appears when you touch UITextField)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the code in which I have added a done button on the left-bottom corner of the keyboard.

What you need to do is to take the idea from thiis and set your button wherever you want on the keyboard.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // create custom button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
        {
            if(isNumPad==YES)
            {
                //[keyboard addSubview:doneButton]; 
            }
            else
            {
                [doneButton removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
        else 
        { 
            [doneButton removeFromSuperview];

        }}
}
- (void)doneButton:(id)sender 
{

//YOUR CODE ON DONE BUTTON CLICKED
}
```

hAPPY cODING...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there is a non-hacky way to solve this problem. I'd suggest looking into associating an [inputAccessoryView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) with your text field.